# format xml with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to format the below xml to the html format specified below.
Basically the content needs to be separated to individual rows based on the tid.
When tid is 1, 1.1 the projects should be shown in the same row.

**My source xml**:

```
<xml>
<projects>
    <dept>
        <emp>
            <Name>Name1<Name>
            <tid>1<tid>
            <proj>Proj1<proj>
        </emp>
        <emp>
            <Name>Name1<Name>
            <tid>1.1<tid>
            <proj>Proj2<proj>
        </emp>
        <emp>
            <Name>Name2<Name>
            <tid>2<tid>
            <proj>Proj3<proj>
        </emp>
        <emp>
            <Name>Name2<Name>
            <tid>2.1<tid>
            <proj>Proj4<proj>
        </emp>
        <emp>
            <Name>Name2<Name>
            <tid>2.2<tid>
            <proj>Proj5<proj>
        </emp>
        <emp>
            <Name>Name3<Name>
            <tid>3<tid>
            <proj>Proj6<proj>
        </emp>
    </dept>
</projects>
```

**Expected format:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>tid</td>
    <td>proj1</td>
    <td>proj2</td>
    <td>proj3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Proj1</td>
    <td>Proj2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name3</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Proj3</td>
    <td>Proj4</td>
    <td>Proj5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Proj6</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome Bharath.  What have you tried?  You'll get the most help by posting your XSL too.

Comment: The names in the output do not seem to match the input. And why are there 2 empty cells in the last table row? -- In any case, this is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Also note that your XML input is not well-formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a standard grouping problem with

```
substring-before(concat(tid,'.') '.')
```

as the grouping key.

The solution to grouping problems depends very much on whether this is XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, but you can find examples in any XSLT textbook or tutorial once you know that "grouping" is the keyword to search for.